# How to write code correctly following the principles and conventions of coding in such situations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, solid

In my applications, users can buy services  on the following route POST `/api/orders/services`
I have created 2 entities in db:

- "orders" table for ordering and billing

```
id amount methodId
```

- The "order_services" table for storing additional parameters about the service, this can be the quantity, the time the service was provided, etc.

```
id orderId attributeId valueId
```

If we stick to the "Single Responsibility" principle, then my code should probably look like this:

```
class Order {
  amount: number;
  methodId: number;
  
  constructor(data: IOrder) {
    this.amount = data.amount;
    this.methodId = data.methodId;
  }

  async create() {
     const result = await DB.createOrder(this.amount, this.methodId);
     return result;
  }
}

class OrderService {
  orderId: number;
  attributeId: number;
  valueId: number;
  
  constructor(data: IOrderService) {
    this.orderId = data.orderId;
    this.attributeId = data.attributeId;
    this.valueId = data.valueId;
  }

  async create() {
     const result = await DB.createOrderService(this.orderId, this.attributeId, this.valueId);
     return result;
  }
}
```

That is, as I understand this principle, OrderService should not create an entry in the "orders" table. Is this the correct explanation? 
But this entity cannot exist without an entry created in the "orders" table.

I have the following question. Will it be correct if in the OrderService entity I first create an entry in "orders", and then immediately create an entry in "order_services" or am I still obliged to create a new class to combine these entities?

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm learning. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first thing that should concern you when it comes to breaking SRP is the fact that your entities are able to store themselves in the database. This job is better suited for the entity manager. Then your actual question becomes a no-brainer, no they shouldn't store other entities either. These days most people would use a library or a framework that can handle such relationships for you.
Then there is the question of why you need IOrder and IOrderService. And where does the price come from? A lot of missing context. You may be misusing interfaces to hardcode different prices and services.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be correct if in the `OrderService` entity I first create an entry in "orders"?

No, I wouldn't do that. Your `OrderService` already does contain an `orderId` value, suggesting that the respective order does exist and does not need to be created. (I would actually go as far as storing the whole `Order` object reference to which the service belongs)

So I'd go with

```
class Order {
  constructor(public id: number, public amount: number, public methodId: number) {
  }

  static async create(amount: number, methodId: number) {
    const result = await DB.createOrder(amount, methodId);
    return new this(result.id, result.amount, result.methodId);
  }

  async createService(attributeId: number, valueId: number): Promise<OrderService> {
    return OrderService.create(this, attributeId, valueId);
  }
  // or also
  service(attributeId: number, valueId: number): OrderService {
    return new OrderService(this, attributeId, valueId);
  }
  // to be used as `await order.service(…).save()`
}

class OrderService {
  constructor(public order: Order, public attributeId: number, public valueId: number) {
  }
  get orderId(): number {
    return this.order.id
  }

  static async create(order: Order, attributeId: number, valueId: number) {
     await DB.createOrderService(order.id, attributeId, valueId);
     return new this(order, attributeId, valueId);
  }
  async save(): Promise<void> {
    await DB.createOrUpdateOrderService(this.orderId, this.attributeId, this.valueId);
  }
}
```